# use segue from different tableViewCell at a tableView push to different viewController Can be implementation at storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I always have a question that using segue from different tableViewCell at a same tableView push to different viewController with storyboard can be implementation? E.g. clicked first cell push to the first view controller, selected second cell push to the second view controller, and the whole process uses storyboard segue. Can have anyone tell me this whether be come true?

Answer (score 1):

Create the segue in your storyboard for each kind of cell :

[image]

Then in your method `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` you should specify the kinf of the cells you implement in your tableView, with their Reuse Identifier.
Then the appropriate segue will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Yaa you can do use but you will have to put the logic in `prepareForSegue` method however this is not the best way to do it you should use the `UITableViewDelegate` method `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` this will give you the indexPath and then you can instantiate to any ViewController you want.